# Site/resource recommendations for practising propositional/predicate logic in natural language

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic, book-recommendation

An AI course I am currently taking puts an emphasis on the translation of natural language to logic and vice versa. I am struggling a bit with this, since beyond giving the definitions of the concepts used in predicate logic, my course offers virtually no resources on practicing the translation between the two.

Therefore I am looking for a site/book/any other resource that would have practice problems on translating simple and more complex English sentences translated to logic (and vice versa). I am talking about sentences like "Dolphins don't like nets", "All dads love bad jokes" etc. The resource would preferably contain model answers for further learning.

Comment: Books: Smith's [Formal Logic](https://www.logicmatters.net/ifl/) and Galgary's [forall x](http://forallx.openlogicproject.org/) with solutions.

Comment: Also [Stanford Introduction to Logic](http://intrologic.stanford.edu/homepage/index.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A shout-out for P&t&r Sm&th's *Introduction to Formal Logic* (CUP 2003/2020, but now freely available to download at https://www.logicmatters.net/ifl).

I believe that the author put particular effort into explaining why the languages of predicate logic work in the way that they do, and into giving lots of detailed examples of how to translate step-by-step from English into FOL (the trickier direction). The book's website has unusually detailed answers to the exercises for the relevant chapters.